# Getting resolved value of a Property in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a big problem with MSBuild on Mac. So I can't use conditions because they are sadly not resolved. (WTF)

So I am trying to workaround this problem, but I am stuck. Basically what I don't understand but want to understand is the following thing:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyA>@(SomeItemGroup)</PropertyA>
  <PropertyB>$(PropertyA)</PropertyB>
</PropertyGroup>

<Message Importance="high" Text="$(PropertyA)"/>
<Message Importance="high" Text="$(PropertyB)"/>
```

This example is fine. Both will result in the content of the ItemGroup and will print the message.

Now I have the following example where I am working with Transform:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyA>@(SomeItemGroup->'%(SomeItem)', '')</PropertyA> => One String for List
  <PropertyB>$(PropertyA.Substring(0, 5))</PropertyB> => PropertyA does not resolve
</PropertyGroup>

<Message Importance="high" Text="$(PropertyA)"/>
<Message Importance="high" Text="$(PropertyB)"/>
```

The first message will give me the content of the ItemGroup. But the second message will only return "@(Som", because it doesnt resolve the PropertyA. Is there any chance to force a property to resolve within another property?

Comment: Are the properties defined in a target or statically inside the project?

Comment: Also, which version and platform (`dotnet` cli or mono) are you using?

Comment: It is inside a Target. I am using mono 5.4.1.7. It happened with xbuild. I solved the problem now otherwise, but I discovered that when I create a seperate Target and call this target and return the property, the property is then automatically resolved. Which is somehow confusing me.

Comment: try msbuild instead of xbuild, mono builds msbuild from the same source as microsoft.

Comment: "I solved the problem now otherwise" => I switched to msbuild. But thanks anyways. It seems to me that xbuild has heavy problems.